# How to add shadow to UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, shadow

I want to create a Slide Menu like in Path or Facebook with a shadow between my menu and the UINavigationController with all the content inside. I can add rounded corners to the layer but the shadow I apply to the layer is not shown. What is wrong with that code? It is working if I use a UIViewController instead of the UINavigationController... (The code is inside a view added as rootViewController to the UINavigationController)

The problem is that I don't want to loose the rounded borders of the UINavigationController

```
self.navigationController.view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.navigationController.view.bounds cornerRadius:self.navigationController.view.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
[self.navigationController.view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[self.navigationController.view.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[self.navigationController.view.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
[self.navigationController.view.layer setShadowOpacity:0.5];
[self.navigationController.view.layer setShadowRadius:3];
[self.navigationController.view.layer setCornerRadius:3];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift3

```
self.navigationController?.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
self.navigationController?.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
[self.navigationController.view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

As the name implies, everything outside the layer - including the shadow - is masked.

Comment: Okay, but then I loose the rounded corners?

Comment: Why not adding a "container" view that will have rounded corners and set the backgroundColor to [UIColor clearColor] ?

Answer (score 0):

set `setMasksToBounds` to `NO` .like this

```
[self.navigationController.view.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
```

you can add shadow without loosing corner ,try this with your code

```
[self.navigationController.view setShouldRasterize:YES];
```

set some shadowOffset & try

```
setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 5)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that without loosing the rounded corners?

Comment: I've tried it but I can only apply setShouldRasterize on the layer but then it is not working and also pixelates the view very strong

Answer (score 0):

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "shadow")
```