# UINavigationController Shadow

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Trying to follow the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043038/how-to-add-shadow-to-uinavigationcontroller) to add a shadow to my UINavigationController. However, the method doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code I am using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // ..... etc. ....

    self.navigationController.view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.navigationController.view.bounds cornerRadius:self.navigationController.view.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer setMasksToBounds: NO];
    [self.navigationController.view.layer setShadowColor: [UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [self.navigationController.view.layer setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
    [self.navigationController.view.layer setShadowRadius:3];
    [self.navigationController.view.layer setShadowRadius: 4.0];
    [self.navigationController.view.layer setShadowOpacity: 0.25];
```

No shadow :( (see photo).

[image]

Any ideas why? Thank you for any input.

Comment: In interface builder, perhaps you might want to try moving your mapView lower in the hierarchy.

Comment: Check my answer @Nick B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me: Try to set whatever you are setting to Navigation Bar instead of navigation controller: [image]r

```
self.nvBar.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.nvBar.bounds cornerRadius:self.nvBar.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
        [self.nvBar.layer setShadowColor: [UIColor redColor].CGColor];
    [self.nvBar.layer setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0, 13)];
    [self.nvBar.layer setShadowRadius:3];
    [self.nvBar.layer setShadowRadius: 4.0];
    [self.nvBar.layer setShadowOpacity: 0.15];
```

Comment: in your case use self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer

Comment: Thanks @Mr.T! Yes I needed `self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.[etc]`. Thanks again